# LVM pvmove operation gone bad

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm attempting to remove an old 300GB drive from my volume group and replace it with a shiny, new 1TB drive.

The `pvmove` operation ran until 99.9% and then aborted. I believe this is because I ran `pvcreate` on `/dev/sdf` directly instead of creating a partition. My problem is, it moved the physical extents to `/dev/sdf` but the original drive, `/dev/sdc1` is still in the volume group, and they both have identical extent counts. It seems that my vg has a duplicate set of extents.

Every guide for removing a disk from a vg involves a `pvmove` and a `vgreduce`. Since the extents are duplicate, I don't want to move them; I need to remove them from the vg entirely. How should I do this without damaging the integrity of the existing volume group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pvmove /dev/mydev
```

will try to migrate all extents away from /dev/mydev, but will only be able to do so if there is enough space on the other physical volumes to fit those extents

```
vgreduce volgroup /dev/mydev
```

will then remove /dev/mydev from volgroup, but only if it holds no more extents in volgroup

Did you get an error when pvmove aborted at 99.9%?

edit: ok, your error sounds like you have a mirrored logical volume.  you can convert it to non-mirrored by

```
lvconvert -m0 volgroup/logvol
```

after which you should be able to

```
pvmove /dev/mydev
vgreduce volgroup /dev/mydev
```

Comment: It was `lvm ABORTING: Can't find mirror LV...`

Comment: it sounds like you somehow ended up with a mirrored lvm